# Load next and previous images list with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-gallery

I am trying to create an image gallery with some images inside my root folder. In my view, I have the following code to list first 25 images.

```
<?php 
            $i=0;
              foreach ($list as $k){?>
              <?php if($i==25) break; ?>
                <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="../../TL_PHOTOS/<?php echo $ip.'/'.$k; ?>" > <img src="../../TL_PHOTOS/<?php echo $ip.'/'.$k; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" width=250 height=250 style="padding:25px;"></a>

              <?php $i++; ?>
           <?php } 

        ?>
```

Here $list array have all the images. I need to put a button line `'Load next 25 images'` and display the rest of 25 images along with the existing ones. Is it possible with PHP for loop itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load next 25 images through ajax request and append it into your view page.

You can implement this in CodeIgniter with reference of below php example.

Refer for details:
https://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/

Hope it helps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Thanks...